# Configuration required for a big mysql database around 20GB

Tags: mysql, myisam

I need to host a single machine database (constraints), wherein the database size is roughly 20gb. Most of the tables are in MyISAM. Any way I can actually run it with decent speed ? Alternatives I can look into are : 
TokuDB, Percona, MariaDB.

A few of the tables have around 50-60 million rows. 
So what I want to know is, how much of RAM and possibly what my.cnf settings might be required to host such a database.

Thanks

Comment: Does it really have to be MyISAM? Did you try to run some tests on any reasonable machine to see if there actually are some performance problems? Are your queries and indexing up to the job?

Comment: @jkavalik Basically its a Wordpress database. I tried importing it into innodb and tokudb engines. Observed performance degradation. Previously this database was running on a 64gb machine, but still had slowdowns. The standard columns are indexed.

Comment: was innodb_buffer_pool_size set to some sensible number? If you have 64gb and db has 20gb in innodb tables, then buffer pool of 15-25gb depending on how many other services (php/apache etc) are running there. Do you have slow query log enabled to see whats taking the most time?

Comment: @jkavalik innodb_buffer_pool was set to 4gb initially, as most of the tables are in myisam, and innodb tables that are present are small in size.
When imported into test machines and converted to innodb, no the pool size was set much smaller, around 2gb.

Comment: then that might explain bad performance (at least partially) of innodb, I suppose your key buffer for myisam is not that low and myisam utilizes os/filesystem cache for data pages, so had enough memory available.

Comment: @jkavalik any other thing I might do, apart from actually sharding the db. Also is it better i switch all tables to innodb/tokudb rather than myisam?

Comment: 20GB is actually not such a big db, so sharding should not be needed. I suggest trying innodb with properly configured buffer(s) if it helps you. And check/enable slow query log to see if you have problem with some specific queries or general "slowness" on your current setup - that is probably more important.

Comment: Did you follow all the MyISAM to InnoDB tips in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)?

Comment: "People who use myisam don't care about their data" Forgot who said it, but its quite true. Toku is not right at all for this, go with innodb. There may be some tuning necessary but you will get better performance out of it. 20GB is pretty small.

Comment: @winmutt switched to Aria in MariaDB. Seems to be working noticeably better.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you invested any time in tuning anything anywhere.  Best of luck.

Comment: @winmutt well, I just got this project couple of days back, with a deadline, so doing what I can do best. Regarding tuning, I followed the answer below, and its actually doing good. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main configuration settings are in [my memory blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory).  Most important is 20% of RAM for key_buffer_size.  (However, it does not need to be more than the sum total of `Index_length` of all the `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.  This will also do the arithmetic:

```
SELECT  ENGINE,
    ROUND(SUM(data_length) /1024/1024, 1) AS "Data MB",
    ROUND(SUM(index_length)/1024/1024, 1) AS "Index MB",
    ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024, 1) AS "Total MB",
    COUNT(*) "Num Tables"
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  table_schema not in ("information_schema", "performance_schema")
GROUP BY  ENGINE;
```

Beware of a large WP installation -- it uses one database, hence one directory, for each 'user'.  After thousands of users, the OS will bog down because of this.

TokuDB's niche is elsewhere; I would not expect it to be useful for *this* task.